# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop.dll could not be loaded - Azure CI pipleine - YAML

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, code-coverage

I am using a CI pipeline for building and generating code coverage (.coverage) report for a .net core project.
Also i have a third party tool used to analyze this coverage file.
When i run that tool as part of the build, it throws the below error.

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.CoverageAnalysisException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.VanguardX.VanguardFileReader.IsVanguardCoverageFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(String path, IEnumerable`1 executablePaths, IEnumerable`1 symbolPaths, MissingFileCallback callback)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

is there a way, i can add/install this dll as part of the YAML file/build?

Comment: Which agent do you use, hosted or self-hosted? If it's self-hosted agent, please check if the assembly exists in the folder in my answer. Also, since this issue comes from the third-party tool, can you share more details about that tool? It would be better if we can reproduce the issue on our side and test it directly for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the VS IDE in your agent has Test-related components, the missing assembly should be located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\{VSVersion}\{VSEditon}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform`

1.You can use [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with `copy/xcopy` command to copy the assembly to the folder where your third-party tool exists. **Normally** the tool can find the assembly then if it search its working folder. 2.But if it can't work, you may need to sign the assembly into GAC and do that again.

It's more recommended to use [self-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) for your scenario, so that you have more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also it's convenient for you to sign assembly into GAC.